# GetDirectories not returning "." and ".."

Tags: c#, .net, directory-structure

I wish to list the subdirectories of a given directory so I am using `Directory.GetDirectories(string)`. Everything works fine but I don't see "." and ".." in the return array. Those two shouldn't be there?

Comment: `Those two shouldn't be here?` What two??? Actual Code Please.

Comment: I don't understand what question you're actually asking here. Are you asking if GetDirectories is correctly implemented? Yes, it is.

Answer (score 2):

GetDirectories only returns **sub-directories**.  Not the parent directory, not the current directory.

Documentation:

```
Return Value
Type: System.String[]
An array of the full names (including paths) of subdirectories in the specified path.
```

Comment: thx a lot, is there a method to return every directory ? including . and .. ?

Comment: You could assume every directory has those and add them programatically.  (Accept of course for the top parent directory which doesn't have a parent).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you call as `Directory.GetDirectories(path);` 
then

`.` is the `path` and

`..` is the `new DirectoryInfo(path).Parent.FullName`